# Как удалить часть title через JS?

Tags: javascript

На странице дублирую заголовок этим JS:

```
<script>document.write(document.title) </script>
```

Но туда входит не нужный текст, как-то можно доработать этот код чтобы ненужная часть текста удалялась?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55319/discussion-on-question-by-----title--js).

Answer (score 1):

Задача заключается в том, что бы удалить из строки последние четыре слова и вывести title без этих слов.
Вариант с выводом из бэка, как советовал один из наших товарищей, не получился. Поэтому было предложено решение с помощью js, как обходной путь, обрезать последние 4 слова и выводить на экран.

```js
document.title = "Тестовая строка  для примера. Последние четыре слова нужно удалить."; 
var titleArr = document.title.split(' '); 
titleArr.length = titleArr.length > 4 ? titleArr.length - 4 : titleArr.length; 
var title = titleArr.join(' '); 
document.write(title)
```

Суть такая: разбиваем строку на массив по пробелу, и если titleArr больше 4, то  удаляем последние 4 слова.

Можно, как вариант, если 4 слова и менее поставить заглушку.

```js
document.title = "Тестовая строка  для примера."; 
    var titleArr = document.title.split(' '),
        title = "";
        
    if(titleArr.length <= 4) {
       title = "ЗАГЛУШКА ЕСЛИ ПРИШЛА СТРОКА МЕНЬШЕ 4 СЛОВ";
    } else {
     titleArr.length =  titleArr.length - 4; 
     title = titleArr.join(' '); 
    }
   
    document.write(title)
```

Comment: `и если titleArr больше 4, то  удаляем последние 4 слова.` – то есть, от четырёх слов останутся четыре, а от пяти — одно? )

Comment: @NickVolynkin я, как понял, в title должно хоть что то остаться. Поэтому сделал условие, если удалять слова если больше 4. Конечно если слов меньше = 4, то наверно просто другую заглушку какую то надо выводить